# Injecting static references in Struts action class

Tags: spring, struts

Our application contains struts and spring. Struts action classes are also configured as spring beans in applicationContext.xml. Spring class references are wired to action classes using 'property'.

For Ex.,

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="sampleAction" class="com.arizona.sample.action.SampleAction">
    <property name="sampleManager" ref="sampleManager" />
</bean>
```

In SampleAction, I got to write a static method where it uses 'sampleManager' reference. So, I have configured 'sampleManager' as static variable. At runtime I got a NullPointerExcpetion at the place where 'sampleManager' is used. I have concluded that 'sampleManager' ain't get initialized.

Can anyone please help me in this regard?

P.S.: I have provided setSampleManager(..) and also tried with @Autowired.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192823/spring-wire-a-static-class

Comment: you are writing a static method on your action class?

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself trying to interact with an inherently non-static object (sampleManager) from a static context (method), then your design has some fundamental flaw in it. Go back and refactor your solution to employ proper OO design, don't try to fix it with some ugly hack.