# When to init a Map in a Service called from a Controller in Spring with Dependency Injection?

Tags: java, spring, hashmap, autowired

I have a Controller class which is invoked first in my application. There I was planning to retrieve a value from a Map from a Service class.

Here's the controller:

```
@Controller
public class AppController {

    public Service doSomethingWithTheMap(String key) {
        return ServiceImpl.getMapValueFor(key).exec();
    }
}
```

I get issues because during the initialization, well during the put of values to the Service's Map to be more precise, I require the BeanFactory because the values in the Map are Service implementations.
Doing it in a static block will cause the BeanFactory to be null because it is not injected yet I would guess.

So ending up with this initMap() call makes me feel a bit like ... there should be a better solution.

Any hints somebody?

I have to admit that I am new to Spring and maybe I mess things up here. FYI the Map came into my mind after having endless if else checks deciding which Service to call based on a String input. Therefore I replaced it with the Map and a simple one liner in the Controller.

```
ServiceImpl.getMapValueFor(key).exec();
```

Here' the Service class:

```
@Service
public class ServiceImpl {

private static Map<String, Service> map;

private static ApplicationContext context;

@Autowired
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext factory) {
    this.context = factory;
}

public static Service getMapValueFor(String key) {
    if (map == null) {
        initMap();
    }
    return map.get(key);
}

private static void initMap() {
    /*
     * FIXME: We can not init the map in a static block or directly
     * initialize it since the factory is not injected until execution of a
     * static block and will be null.
     */
    BeanFactory factory = context;
    map = new HashMap<String, Service>();
    map.put("key", factory.getBean(SomeService.class));

}
}
```

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192823/spring-wire-a-static-class

Comment: Thanks @Dave. I see. Looks like my problem really is the initialization order. Tried it now using the constructor way initializing (or wiring) the class containing the map but still, NullPointer because the context/factory is not there during put to the Map.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I want to say is that you have a bug, because you are using a HashMap with no synchronization! - Don't be alarmed many (if not most) java developers would make the same mistake.

Unless you have oversimplified the code, your service looks more like a command than a service; A service is a singleton. It is not impossible for services to have methods without arguments, but I would say it is uncommon. Are you sure you should not be using prototype beans instead of singletons ?

Typically the number of services are finite, and if you have multiple services of the same type you would use the @Qualifier when autowiring them. In any case this code looks dodgy to me, so perhaps you should try to explain the problem at a higher level, because there may be a better way than you current code-path.

Comment: Your wording "command" is exactly correct. I just simplified my code for demo purposes. I called it Service here because I came around the Service and Component annotations of spring. However, what I exactly want to do is calling a Class based on a String value received in my Controller. I will have around 200 pairs of String to Class relations.

Comment: Then the comment on ApplicationContextAware is what you need, give me 10 minutes to whip up an example.

Comment: Where do you get the key from, is it part of user input or ?

Comment: what would you suggest instead? Defining Beans in the Configuration class like [this](https://gist.github.com/in1t5/5e57244e3333c2856d0cea8b5d97a385) maybe?

Comment: the key is from the user exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Your service class ServiceImpl must implement the interface `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware` to get the instance of Spring's application context.

Comment: Thanks for this. Wasn't aware of it. I guess I am overcomplicating things here and am completely working against spring right now.

Comment: @init5, Spring will call your setApplicationContext only if your class having that method implements `ApplicationContextAware`. Try that and let me know if you face any other issues.

Comment: still the NPE during initMap(). Checking for the provider/simple bean approach

Comment: Another observation, if you find yourself writing static methods inside a Spring bean you are typically doing something wrong. Static should be used for utility methods, references to constants and immutable objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic solution, it uses the fact that the name of a @Bean is the name of the method which creates it, you will probably need a better strategy. The idea is to hide getBean inside a Provider class which can then be Autowired (and tested)

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
        CallableProvider provider = ctx.getBean(CallableProvider.class);
        System.out.println(provider.getCommand("aCommand").call());
        System.out.println(provider.getCommand("bCommand").call());
    }

    public static class Config {
        @Bean
        public ACommand aCommand() {
            return new ACommand();
        }
        @Bean
        public BCommand bCommand() {
            return new BCommand();
        }

        @Bean
        public CallableProvider callableProvider() {
            return new CallableProvider();
        }
    }

    public static class CallableProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {
        private ApplicationContext context;

        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
            this.context = applicationContext;
        }

        public Command getCommand(String name) {
            return context.getBean(name, Command.class);
        }
    }

    public static class ACommand implements Command {
        // autowire stuff
        @Override
        public String call()  {
            return "A";
        }
    }

    public static class BCommand implements Command {
        // autowire stuff
        @Override
        public String call()  {
            return "B";
        }
    }

    public interface Command {
        String call();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok I got your point. So basically I would define all my commands with the Bean annotation and have the provider implementing the ApplicationContextAware for the wiring to work. I will check this and let you know. And of course I have to init my map somewhere because my user input differs from the bean names hehe

Comment: If you plan to use a Map in a controller, it is accessed by multiple threads. Typically you would use ConcurrentHashMap for this because it is thread-safe, if you use HashMap, you must synchronize the initialization and every access.

Comment: Great, it worked. Also with the map. Your idea of using the equality of bean names and methods brought me to [this](https://github.com/in1t5/spring-annotating). I removed the Map and the bean definitions in the config class. Instead I am directly naming the beans while they are scanned by Spring with `@Component("A")`. Spring is telling: _Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'A'_. Afterwards I can directly call `ctx.getBean("A", Command.class).exec()` in the Controller. What you think? Or am I somehow misusing the annotation?

Comment: The naming using @Component is fine, however it requires that your Component are threadsafe, since Components/Serives/Repositories are signletons by default, so if two user's simultaneously wants to execute command A, they will both call execute on the same instance, and in that case any access to fields in A must be done in a threadsaft manner.